# VIM inconsistent indentation

Tags: vim, indentation, autoindent

I have the following small Specman (.e) file:   (set filetype=specman)

```
<'
extend sys {
    a : b;
    !enable : bool;
    run() is also {
        message (LOW, "Hello World"); 
    };
};
'>
```

Which was nicely indented by typing with smart-indent enabled.

However, if I try to automatically indent all typed code (gg=G), I get this strange snippet:

```
<'
extend sys {
a : b;
    !enable : bool;
    run() is also {
        message (LOW, "Hello World"); 
    };
};
'>
```

I have "nolisp, nocindent, autoindent, smartindent".

Thanks,
Zvika

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `vim` is interpreting that line as a case label. Try playing around with the `cinoptions` according to http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values.